# "Used to have to" meaning

Tags: meaning, sentence

I know that "used to" is used for an action that is no longer done. But I want to know if I could use "have to" with it. For example if I want to say that getting up early in the morning everyday was something that I never enjoyed thus I had to do it everyday regardless of my unwillingness to do it so the sentence that I think correct is:

> I used to have to get up early in the morning.

So does it convey the meaning that I want it to convey? All I want to say is that I didn't like to do it but I had to to it everyday.

Comment: Just a side note, 'used to' is possible for situations that are true (again), for example : "I used to live in London a long time ago, then I lived abroad and now I am back here in London again!" I think what is important is that the repeated action (or state) was stopped/interrupted.

Answer (score 2):

I used to have to do x. = idiomatic.

I used to have to get up early in the morning but now I don't have to.
I used to have to leave work very late but now I leave on time.

**used to have to do something** is perfectly idiomatic and so is the sentence above.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, but not very common. It sounds "clumsy" and is rare in elegant written English. It would be more fluent to use the simple past with some time expression:

> When I worked at the car factory, I had to get up early in the morning.

Or describe the fact that you didn't like it in other words

> I used to get up early, but I always wanted to stay in bed.